# How to recursively create a Modal with an array of data in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I need to recursively add these comments in the correct order.

Currently i get an array of comments that are unsorted.
These comments can be the top level or can be a child of the top level.

I was using this recursive method to add them but i can’t seem to get it right.

The result should be an array of CommentModal’s `[CommentModal]`

For reference:
The `postID` is the `topLevel` comment that the child belongs to. Every child comment will have a `postID` so that they know where they belong to. If the child has a child, the top level child’s `commentID` will be the child’s `postID`.

#### Data and Data Models

```
struct Comment {
    var postID: String
    var commentID: String
    var date: Double
}

class CommentModal {
    var mainComment: Comment
    var childComment: [CommentModal] = []
    
    init(mainComment: Comment) {
        self.mainComment = mainComment
    }
}

let data: [Comment] = [
    Comment(postID: "RootPostID", commentID: "116", date: 1),
    Comment(postID: "RootPostID", commentID: "117", date: 2),
    Comment(postID: "RootPostID", commentID: "118", date: 3),
    Comment(postID: "116",      commentID: "216", date: 4),
    Comment(postID: "117",      commentID: "217", date: 5),
    Comment(postID: "118",      commentID: "218", date: 6),
    Comment(postID: "216",      commentID: "316", date: 7),
    Comment(postID: "216",      commentID: "317", date: 8),
]
```

#### Initialized

```
private func index(comments: [Comment]) {
        discardableCachedComments = comments
        commentModalArray = addChildren(from: comments)
    }
```

```
    private func addChildren(from comments: [Comment]) -> [CommentModal] {
        var result: [CommentModal] = []
        
        for comment in comments {
            let children = discardableCachedComments.filter { $0.postID == comment.commentID }
            discardableCachedComments.removeAll { $0.postID == comment.commentID }
            
            let commentModal = CommentModal(mainComment: comment)
            
            if children.count >= 1 {
                commentModal.childComment = addChildren(from: children)
            }
            discardableCachedComments.removeAll { $0.commentID == comment.commentID }
            result.append(commentModal)
        }
        
        return result
    }
```

#### Desired Output

Using the `data` above i want to see the result be:

An array of 3 Top Level CommentModals.
Each of those Top Level CommentModals will have a `childComment` which is an array of `CommentModal`. For one of those `childComment` we will also see it have two values in `childComment`.

If you see the data you will see how the `postID` and `commentID` are assembled so that they are added correctly in its respective modal.

Comment: Are `CommentModel` and `CommentModal` the same? Can you include an example of what the desired/input output should be from the function? Also, you have some SwiftUI tags here that don't seem to be related to the code you've shared.

Comment: @jnpdx yea sorry. I updated the question. It is supposed to be `CommentModal` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed a couple of names to make things semantically a little easier to understand, but this should show the gist of it. I've also changed `CommentModal` into a `struct`, since that made initialization easier, but you could change it back.

This should be copy/pastable into a Playground:

```
struct Comment : Codable {
    var parentID: String
    var id: String
    var date: Double
}

struct CommentModel : Codable {
    var comment: Comment
    var children: [CommentModel] = []
}

let data: [Comment] = [
    Comment(parentID: "RootPostID", id: "116", date: 1),
    Comment(parentID: "RootPostID", id: "117", date: 2),
    Comment(parentID: "RootPostID", id: "118", date: 3),
    Comment(parentID: "116",      id: "216", date: 4),
    Comment(parentID: "117",      id: "217", date: 5),
    Comment(parentID: "118",      id: "218", date: 6),
    Comment(parentID: "216",      id: "316", date: 7),
    Comment(parentID: "216",      id: "317", date: 8),
]

func createCommentModels(rootKey: String, input: [Comment]) -> [CommentModel] {
    return input
        .filter { $0.parentID == rootKey }
        .map { comment in
            return CommentModel(comment: comment,
                                children: createCommentModels(rootKey: comment.id,
                                                              input: input
                                                              ))
        }
}

func printModal(_ input: CommentModel, indent: Int = 0) {
    let indentChars = Array(repeating: " ", count: indent).joined(separator: "")
    print("\(indentChars)", input.comment.id)
    if !input.children.isEmpty {
        print("\(indentChars) - Children:")
        input.children.forEach { printModal($0, indent: indent + 4)}
    }
}

let result = createCommentModels(rootKey: "RootPostID", input: data)

result.forEach {
    printModal($0)
}
```

Which yields:

```
116
 - Children:
     216
     - Children:
         316
         317
 117
 - Children:
     217
 118
 - Children:
     218
```